# How do I compute a "CRC code word" from an information word and CRC polynomial?

Tags: error-correcting-codes, crc

I have the CRC polynomial 1101, and my information word is 10001111. How do I find the CRC code word?

Disclaimer: This is an assignment problem. I'd appreciate any help, particularly solving the problem for a different polynomial and word. Most of all, I'd like an explanation of what to do here, and what a CRC code word actually is, since I don't really understand the question. Though the code word is the answer for my problem, that isn't what I'm looking for here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Computation